# How to get video and playlist descriptions using youtube player in an app?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I created an app using youtube player and using the default layout. How do I set the layout using the player so for playlists I use so in portrait mode I have the video on top then scrollable list of descriptions  under it? Seems like we should be able to specify that layout without creating our own layouts to do the same thing. I am using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.

Thanks,
-Tony

Comment: So what's the real problem? The details you provided doesn't seem to be connected the title of your question.

Comment: The problem is time and effort to create a look like what you see in youtube player when it has a playlist. I can probably google and find something like that and involves a lot of coding or if Google had thought about it is have a way to reuse that look and feel for say a fragment but have a config to do so already.